# How to get large pictures in Google image

Tags: web, web-scraping, google-crawlers, webharvest

I want to collect pictures from Google image search. However, I am constantly notified with an error.

For example, the URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=banana&amp;hl=en&gws_rd=ssl&tbm=isch` is fine in my browser, but in web harvest it reports that: the reference to entity "gws_rd" must end with the ';' delimiter.

I guess '&' is a special character in webharvest, but I cannot find information about it. Can you figure out why?

This is the code:

```
<var-def name="search" overwrite="false">banana</var-def>

<var-def name="url"><template>http://images.google.com/images?q=${search}&amp;hl=en</template></var-def>
<var-def name="xml">
    <html-to-xml>
        <http url="${url}"/>
    </html-to-xml>
</var-def>
<var-def name="largeImgUrl">
    <xpath expression="//*[@id='irc_cc']/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/img">
        <var name="xml"/>
    </xpath>
</var-def>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the ampersands to &amp; ?

Comment: Thank you, but you mean change the url into https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=banana&amp;hl=ento&amp;gws_rd=sslto&amp;tbm=isch  ? It works, but  the html I got in web-harvest is different from the one in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

from experience you will need to first store the url in a variable, and then refer to the variable from within the http processor call

### EDIT

I notice you have pasted your code.  Good.

1) remember that all the webharvest config files are written in XML,  and amersand **&** is a special character in  XML,  as it is part of the [entity declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)
In webharvest i normaly avoid this issue by using [CDATA sections](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)  within `<template>` or `<code>` blocks.

2)when using webharvest graphical interface,  you can easily debug your xpath expressions.  Run your code as normal,  and then on the toolbar at the top click the icon with a magniffying glass.  Then choose "xml" (name of your variable you have set). This will open a new window,  with a preview of your xml. Make sure the "view as" dropdown is set to xml.
You should now have a "xpath expression" box where you can test your xpath.
[image: webharvest variable preview]

3)I strongly discourage from writing xpaths referring to numbered elements. (eg `div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/`).  Any small change in the underlying page usually breaks the code.  It is much better to select elements based on id or other properties.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I've update my post. I use google chrome to help me find the expression of xpath, that is 'inspect element' and 'copy xpath'. The code example shown above is intended to get the url of the first large picture. But it turns out that largeImgUrl is empty.